# Unique social shares

Tags: facebook, unique, sharing, social-media

I've got a question that I just can't find out the answer to.

I am working on an application in which users can share content through facebook, however they are only allowed to share each piece of content once and once only.

I need to find a way (Without storing share data locally in a database somewhere) to get the amount of unique shares for a URL. Can this be done using the facebook API? Or would I need to use a facebook application as a middlepoint to make sure people can't share more than once?

Answer (score 0):

You surely cant do this using Facebook API

You can only get the number of shares for a url by -

For eg. to findout the number of shares for the url `http://yahoo.com`

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://yahoo.com
```

Not sure whether the number of shares returned by this method are unique or not